# Javascript loop through multiple forms, get all input values

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I need to build an object from multiple forms input values without using jQuery.

```
    <div id="formMain">
    <form id="form_id_1" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" value="Joe">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" value="1st Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form id="form_id_2" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" id="name1" value="Mary">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" id="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" id="addressId" value="2nd Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

final result should be object:

```
"profile":[
{
   "name":"Joe",
   "name2":"Doe",
   "address":"1st Maint Street",
},
{
    "name":"Mary",
    "name2":"Doe",
    "address":"2nd Maint Street",
 },
```

The forms can be added dynamically by user, so I can have multiple forms embedded in the main form div.

I´m able to get the the first form values, but I´m getting stuck when multiple forms are added, I trying to loop throough the main element but just not working. The above is my 1st code sample working.

```
var formdata = document.getElementById('formMain').getElementsByTagName('input')
var form = [].map.call(formdata, function( input ) {
    return {'value':input.value};
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this - using querySelectorAll, forEach and push.

Alternatively Array.map as long as the callback returns the objects created. 
the HTML element collection needs to be cast to an Array to use map

```js
console.log("Using forEach on the HTML collection")

let profile = [];
document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(f => {
  let obj = {};
  f.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(ele => obj[ele.name] = ele.value || "");
  profile.push(obj)
})
console.log(profile)

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

console.log("Using Array.map on a HTML collection cast to Array")

profile = [...document.querySelectorAll("form")].map(f => {
  let obj = {};
  f.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(ele => obj[ele.name] = ele.value || "");
  return obj;
})
console.log(profile)
```

```html
<div id="formMain">
  <form id="form_id_1" class="formClass">
    <div id="fullname">
      <p>Full Name</p>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" value="Joe">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" value="Doe">
    </div>
    <div id="Address">
      <p>Address</p>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" value="1st Maint Street">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form id="form_id_2" class="formClass">
    <div id="fullname">
      <p>Full Name</p>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" id="name1" value="Mary">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" id="name2" value="Doe">
    </div>
    <div id="Address">
      <p>Address</p>
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" id="addressId" value="2nd Maint Street">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
var result = Array.from(forms).map(a => {
 var obj = {};
 Array.from(a.querySelectorAll("[name]")).forEach(b => {
  obj[b.getAttribute("name")] = b.value;
 });
 return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
   <div id="formMain">
    <form id="form_id_1" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" value="Joe">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" value="1st Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form id="form_id_2" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" id="name1" value="Mary">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" id="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" id="addressId" value="2nd Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `querySelectorAll` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)) can be used to fetch the forms and inputs.
- `flatMap` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)) can be used to map forms to inputs.
- spread syntax `[...iterable]` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) can be used to convert the node list returned by `querySelectorAll` to an array.

```js
let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('form')].flatMap(a => [...a.querySelectorAll('input')]);
console.log(inputs);
```

```html
<div id="formMain">
    <form id="form_id_1" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" value="Joe">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" value="1st Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form id="form_id_2" class="formClass">
        <div id="fullname">
            <p>Full Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" id="name1" value="Mary">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" id="name2" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div id="Address">
            <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" id="addressId" value="2nd Maint Street">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You get the inputs but not the name/values

Comment: getting names & values from the elements is trivial and not as generalize-able.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```js
var formMain = document.getElementById("formMain");
var formMresultAreaain = document.getElementById("resultArea");
var result = [];
var formData = '<form class="formClass">' +
  '<div id="fullname">' +
  '<p>Full Name</p>' +
  '<input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name" value="Joe">' +
  '<br/>' +
  '<input type="text" class="inputClass" name="name2" value="Doe">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div id="Address">' +
  '<p>Address</p>' +
  '<input type="text" class="inputClass" name="address" value="1st Maint Street">' +
  '</div>' +
  '</form>';

function addForm() {
  formMain.innerHTML += formData;
}

function submitForms() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  var inputs;
  var tempResult = {};
  result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    inputs = forms[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
    tempResult = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
      tempResult[inputs[j].name] = inputs[j].value;
    result.push(tempResult);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addForm()" value="Add Form" />

<div id="formMain">

</div>

<hr/>

<input type="button" onclick="submitForms()" value="Submit" />
```